# Yodlee Favicons are not displaying

Tags: java, php, yodlee

Favicons are not displaying images when calling the url for favicons given by the yodlee.

When calling the url of the yodlee interactive (REST) Api, mentioned below -

/account/summary/all

i am getting all accounts along with accounts information.

In that i have seen something as follows

"favicon": {
                            "href": "https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/imagecache.restserver.do?icon=favicon&sum_info_id=11195"
                        }

When clicking on the above favicon url i am unable to see the favicon.

For more information please refer the following link

https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/Account/Summary/All

Can anybody please provide me the solution for this .
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should call [getSiteInfo](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getSiteInfo) to get the details for the specific site, with siteFilter.reqSpecifier's value as 128 and this will return you the logo and favicon in byte array. You can then convert it into image and use it.